# vaadin. running 2 spring apps simultaneously

Tags: spring, spring-boot, vaadin, internals

I have a multi-module spring gradle app. 2 modules are executable, both modules use vaadin 14.1.17. I use a remote server to deploy two jar at the same time, but every time I run the second application, the first breaks. help to understand what the problem is. stacktrace broken application:

```
com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapException: Unable to read webpack stats file.
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler$BootstrapPageBuilder.setupFrameworkLibraries(BootstrapHandler.java:872) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler$BootstrapPageBuilder.setupDocumentHead(BootstrapHandler.java:749) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler$BootstrapPageBuilder.getBootstrapPage(BootstrapHandler.java:524) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.BootstrapHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(BootstrapHandler.java:465) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:40) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1540) ~[flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:247) [flow-server-2.1.5.jar!/:2.1.5]
at com.vaadin.flow.spring.SpringServlet.service(SpringServlet.java:95) [vaadin-spring-12.1.2.jar!/:na]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:352) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.30.jar!/:9.0.30]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletForwardingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletForwardingController.java:141) [spring-webmvc-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.3.RELEASE]
```

each application runs on a separate port. In addition, before the first call through a web browser, the first application does not break. I launch applications on a Linux server as a systemd service.
I repeat again. Before I access through the browser, both services are running and do not contain errors. But after I access the FIRST running application, it crashes, but the second continues to work

Comment: The error posted here would indicate, that the application there is not built in production mode.  Unrelated to the error abouve, you would have configure the cookie name of either or both applications if you want to run them behind the same domain name (or else the same cookie ends up in two different applications and smashes the state in both)

Comment: I tried to run applications in different combinations, both in production mode, both in development mode. Constantly some mistakes. If vaadin.compatibilityMode = true is used in one of the services, then everything works fine. Even without cookie settings